# cakephp 2.1 view associated data across all add.ctp, edit.ctp, view.ctp

Tags: view, cakephp-2.1, relation

I have an "examinations" table, its consultation_id relates to "consulsations" table, which in turn its consulation_id relates to the "patients" table.

Now, when I am in the add.ctp, edit.ctp or view.ctp of the "Examinations" Views I need to pull the "patients" details in so that some patient info can appear as to who the form pertains to as patient.

I have tried joins. Not to say they dont work. I am new to cakephp and I really need help as to how it will appear within the controller and how the view.ctp will display it.

I thought of elements but they are just .ctp files right?

Please if anyone can help regarding this it would be so appreciated. I've been trying to do this now for a week and I know there is something simple I am dont doing or thinking rights about.

Answer (score 0):

So you just want to pull in related data? Pretty simple.

In your `ExaminationsController` methods.

```
$patients = $this->Examination->Consultation->Patient->find('all',
array('conditions'=>array('consultation_id'=>$id,'examination_id'=>$e_id)));
```

Something similar to this, not quite sure on which id you need to pass, as it will depend on how your models are linked up. http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/retrieving-your-data.html

However, if your models are linked up properly, you should get this data anyway. If not set your models recursion to be higher.

```
$this->Model->recursive = 2;
```